# Webservice class with parser using generics

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm currently building a small web stack in swift for use in my iOS apps. It consists of multiple components and I want to make it resource specific;
To that end, I have a `WebService` class composed of two parts; a part that handles the request logic, and a part that handles the parsing.

The catch here is that the parsing is defined by a `ParserType` protocol with an associated type `ModelType`, which needs to be specified by the adopter. It parses `Any?` to that `ModelType`:

```
public protocol ParserType {

    associatedtype ModelType

    func parse(_ data: Any?) throws -> ModelType
}
```

This is no problem on its own; a concrete parser could look like this (just forgive me the force casting here):

```
public class SimpleJSONParser<T: Codable>: ParserType {

    public typealias ModelType = T
    private let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder

    public init(jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) {
        self.jsonDecoder = jsonDecoder
    }


    open func parse(_ data: Any?) throws -> T {
        let response = try jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: data as! Data)
        return response
    }
}
```

Now we have a concrete JSON parser that tries to parse `Any?` to `T`. That's cool, so we want to inject it into `WebService`, so it can be used. It looks like this:

```
public class WebService<ModelType, Parser: ParserType> {

    public typealias ModelType = Parser.ModelType
    public typealias WebServiceCompletion = (Result<ModelType>) -> Void

    private let endpoint: String
    private let parser: Parser
    private let transport: ServiceTransport

    public init(transport: ServiceTransport, endpoint: String, parser: Parser) {
        self.transport = transport
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.parser = parser
    }

    @discardableResult
    open func fetch(path: String? = nil, headers: [String: String]? = nil, parameters: [String: String]? = nil, autoResumeTask: Bool = true, completion: @escaping WebServiceCompletion) -> ServiceTransportTask {

        let endpointToUse = endpoint + (path ?? "")

        let task = transport.perform(action: .get, path: endpointToUse, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, body: nil)
                .completion { response in
                    switch response {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    case .success(let data):
                        do {
                            let result: ModelType = try self.parser.parse(data)
                            completion(.success(result))
                        } catch let error {
                            completion(.failure(error))
                        }
                    }
                }

        if autoResumeTask {
            task.resume()
        }

        return task
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that when I want to use this, I have to specify to the `WebService` that I want to use it for a type `CategoryArray` for example, with a parser that parses JSON to CategoryArray, i.e. `JSONParser<CategoryArray>`, and then also inject such a parser into the `WebService`:

```
let transport = HTTPTransport(baseURL: URL(string: baseURLString)!)
let parser = JSONParser<CategoryArray>()
let webService: WebService<CategoryArray, JSONParser<CategoryArray>> webService = WebService(transport: transport, endpoint: endPoint, parser: parser)
```

It feels a bit weird to me in the sense that I have to define the model type to use in both `WebService` and `Parser`, and also define the parser type.

Is my approach too **generic**, or can I factor out something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can just use the generic `ModelType` defined in the `ParserType`, and I don't need the same generic parameter in `WebService`;

```
public class WebService<Parser: ParserType> {
...
```

The typealias is just for convenience, to not type `ParserType.ModelType` everywhere but just `ModelType`.

Results in this call site:

```
let transport = HTTPTransport(baseURL: URL(string: baseURLString)!)
let parser = JSONParser<CategoryArray>()
let webService: WebService<JSONParser<CategoryArray>> webService = WebService(transport: transport, endpoint: endPoint, parser: parser)
```

(And because of type inference, the last line can be reduced to `let webService = WebService(transport: transport, endpoint: endPoint, parser: parser)` which is neat)